# IC7300 soundcard issues

Tags: software, equipment-troubleshooting, icom-ic-7300, wsjt-x, windows

I have a brand new Dell XPS laptop running windows 11 pro. The rig is an IC7300 which I had running WSJT-x (JTDX) as well as other digi modes using ham radio deluxe fine on an older (10 year old machine) windows 10 laptop.I have everything running fairly correct.. it will decode and transmit but wsjt and other digi modes are hearing (i see it on the waterfall) noise inside the room. The only way i can stop it is completely turn the mic off on the computer. Ive turned off all app access to the mic one by one and nothing works except to turn the mic off. the receive level in wsjt-x wont go any lower than 108 no matter what volume settings i use and ham radio deluxe (in DM780) says im overloading the receive as well. I uninstalled and reinstalled the icom drivers a couple times. Even tried using the machine souncard and nothing will fix it.I have the 7300 settings exactly as the hamradiodeluxe site says to have them. Hope someone else has had this issue and can help me out. The only thing thats changed from my original working setup is the new laptop.

Comment: Might be an incompatibility bug between WSJT and Win11.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning how the Windows may connect the inputs ("Recording" channels) and the outputs ("Playback" channels), there are some ways you can hear the input channels in the output channels.

1. An input channel (microphone, etc.) has the "Monitor" switch turned on that copies the sound from that channel directly to the output channels by software. You can find it in the sound settings.
2. Sound cards usually have a special input channel that has all the other channels connected to it on the sound card itself. There is no naming standard, so the name of this channel can be literally anything, e.g. "What U Hear", "Stereo Mix", "Wave Out", and so on. Don't be confused: this is an input channel your software can connect to to hear what it "plays".

This function is theoretically obsolete because from Windows Vista, there is a software loopback capability for every output channel on Windows to be used as an input channel (WSS), but still provided and used by the manufacturers.

You did not give enough information but if the phenomenon happens to your digital communication programs, you might have set them to use this "What You hear" channel instead of a "Line In" or so, otherwise your microphone's input channel might have that standard monitoring capability turned on in the Windows's sound settings of that device, and your software is set up to use an output channel ("Speakers", "Headphones", etc.) as an input channel - containing the sound of monitored inputs such as your microphone.